# Volume of the region E lying above the plane $z=2-2x-2y$ and below the paraboloid $z=2-x^2-y^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to find the volume of the region E lying above the plane $z=2-2x-2y$ and below the paraboloid $z=2-x^2-y^2$ using polar coordinates.

So far I did this:
$$
x^2+y^2=2x+2y
$$
$$
r^2=2r\cos\theta+2r\sin\theta
$$
$$
r=2\cos\theta+2\sin\theta
$$
$$
V=\int\int\int rdzdA
$$

but, I'm not sure how to set up the bounds for the integral.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 + y^2 = 2x + 2y\\
(x -1)^2 + (y-1)^2 = 2$

Since our region of interest is centered at $(1,1)$ lets shift our coordinates to compensate.

$x = r\cos\theta + 1\\
y = r\sin\theta + 1$

this shift does nothing to the jacobian.

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt 2} (2-r^2) r\ dr \ d\theta$

Comment: so, the answer would be $2\pi$?

Comment: It is $2\pi$ with this traslated version of polar coordinates.  Had I stayed with the more traditional polar coordinates, then the entire region is to the northeast of $y=-x.$ and $-\frac {\pi}{4}$ to $\frac {3\pi}{4}$ would be the appropriate bounds.